# Background color in div doesn't work in iphone

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've done some media queries for the site http://www.domda.se
The problem is that the backgroundcolours in #middle and #bottom doesn´t work when I look at the site on an iphone. The problem started when I added -1 margins to prevent gaps between the divs. I've tried to remove the negative margins to see if that helps but it didn't work.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this rule, into this media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
/* ...some other stuff here... */
    #middle {
        background: #00ffff;
        float: none;
        margin: -1px 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
    }
/* ...some more stuff here... */
```

Can you try to add `overflow:hidden;` ? Also in the `#bottom` :

```
#bottom {
    background: #fff;
    float: none;
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    overflow:hidden; /* ADD THIS PROPERTY ON BOTH */
}
```

I think the problem is that you're removing the `float`, so the container will not ... contain its contents anymore.